# getmethod(methodname,new[]Type) in Type arrays contains ref parameter and method is overrided

Tags: c#-3.0

For example

```
class xx
{
    public string name
    {
        get {return "";}
    }
}

class yy
{
    public string name(string n)
    {
         return "";
    }

    public string name(string n,ref string m)
    {
        return "";
    }

    public string name(string n,string m,ref xx k)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

How to get "name" method by reflection technology ?

Comment: how to get "name" method by reflection technology

Comment: You can edit your question rather than posing a comment... Which "name" method are you talking about ? why are you talking aout overriding ? There's no overriden method in your code

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do it using `GetMethod`. However, you can easily do it with `GetMethods` and Linq :

```
var methodInfo = from m in typeof(yy).GetMethods()
                 where m.Name == "name"
                 let prms = m.GetParameters()
                 where prms.Length == 3
                 && prms[0].ParameterType == typeof(string)
                 && prms[1].ParameterType == typeof(string)
                 && prms[2].ParameterType == typeof(xx).MakeByRefType()
                 select m;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Type.MakeByRefType()`-Method to create an ref type param. The rest is done by reflection classes.

```
var method = typeof(yy).GetMethod(
    "name", 
    new[] {typeof(string), typeof(string).MakeByRefType()});
```